# How to receive a jsonp request in golang

Tags: javascript, jquery, go, jsonp

I send some data using jquery in the jsonp format  :

```
console.log(data.location.lng);
console.log(data.location.lat);
console.log(data.accuracy);
var urlgr = "http://127.0.0.1:9220/geo/rec_geo/";
var pfg = {
    //lo: data.location.lng,
    lo: 1.0,
    //la: data.location.lat,
    la: 2.0,
    //ac: data.accuracy,
    ac: 3,
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlgr,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(pfg),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("data rec geo");
        console.log(data);

    }
});
```

here is my code in golang to receive it  :

```
type geoData struct {
    Long float32 `json:"lo"`
    Lat   float32  `json:"la"`
    Accuracy  int `json:"ac"`
}

func recordGeo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    s := strings.Split(r.RemoteAddr, ":")
    ip := s[0]
    Info.Println("4")
    var geoRec geoData
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    err := decoder.Decode(&geoRec)
    fmt.Println("geoRec")
    fmt.Println(geoRec)
    checkErr(err)
}
```

but i have a EOF error  :

```
2017/07/01 07:16:22 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:50680: EOF
```

So my question is how to properly receive a jsonp request in golang and parse it to a struct ?

here is the request that i get in the golang server side  :

```
GET /geo/rec_geo/?callback=jQuery31108538596418163691_1498913991164&{%22lo%22:1,%22la%22:2,%22ac%22:3}&_=1498913991166 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9220
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
referer: http://localhost:8080/
cookie: csrftoken=Y7WA181u22l9sScw9UbPxM38wCGQzjaLMMysAesJSWZm89Pj6CCdBkEF01ibpUjW
alexatoolbar-alx_ns_ph: AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.1
connection: keep-alive
```

edit removed the : 
Info.Println line
but i still have the same error

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your `golang` code, the following lines:

```
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
Info.Println(r.Body)
err := decoder.Decode(&geoRec)
```

Both `Info.Println` and `decoder.Decode` read from request body which is an `io.Reader`. After the execution of `Info.Println`, the reader is at `EOF` state. From this point, any further `Read` will result in `EOF` error, the error you saw in your application. If you remove (comment out) `Info.Println`, you will be able to decode the data to the struct.

**EDIT:**
I forgot and didn't paying attention that JSONP is `GET` request. The JSON data is embedded in the query. Try the following approach to extract JSON data (please adapt to your need).

```
//snippet inside recordGeo function
//...

callback := ""
geoRec := geoData{}
queries := r.URL.Query()

//See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
//for 'jsonp' data type parameters.
for key, val := range queries {
    if key == "callback" {
        callback = val[0]
    } else if key == "_" {
        //the Timestamp
    } else {
        //JSON data in the key
        dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(key))
        err := dec.Decode(&geoRec)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        log.Printf("DATA=%#v", geoRec)
    }
}

//...
//do some processing
response := "{YOUR RESPONSE DATA}"
if callback != "" {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/javascript")
    response = fmt.Sprintf("%s(%s);", callback, response)
}
w.Write([]byte(response))
```

If in the client side you set the data as `data: pfg` (without `JSON.stringify`), then in the server side, each parameter will be accessible through query parameter:

```
//
lon := queries.Get("lo")
lat := queries.Get("la")
acc := queries.Get("ac")
```

OR, if you set the AJAX request data as `data: "mydata=" + JSON.stringify(pfg)`, then you can extract the data as:

```
mydata := queries.Get("mydata")
dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(mydata))
err := dec.Decode(&geoRec)
```

After processing, you need to send a proper JSONP response to the client, i.e. `callback(DATA);`.

Comment: Even with removing the info.Println i still have the same EOF error ...

Comment: @user462794 to debug, just after `recordGeo` function, use [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) to read the content of the request body, then print it to the console and post it here.

Comment: @user462794 I've edit the answer, please take a look

Comment: fmt.Sprintf rather than fmt.Printf near the end

Comment: @spekary, Thank you. Answer was modified.

Answer (score 1):

`JSONP` is to receive data from the server not the other way around.

You can read more about JSONP - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584) and [JSONP examples](https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/).

Actually it's not specific to Go language, you can implement JSONP handling in any server-side programing.

---

For your purpose, it seems you need JSON Post request from JavaScript/Jquery. And on Go lang handler do-

```
func recordGeo(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    var geoRec geoData
    if err := decoder.Decode(&geoRec); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer req.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(geoRec)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue. Then I found the echo framework (namely `github.com/labstack/echo` package and its middleware) which can perfectly handle the jsonp request. Here is the demo, [cook for jsonp](https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/jsonp)

Hope this could help.